# Symbol for current, ongoing event

Tags: design, icons, interface, symbols

In my app I need to display an icon for an event which is currently ongoing. It's a forecast app for forecasters, where they can issue a forecast in certain time window (event). I'm currently using a plane icon from fontawesome, but I'm not sure at all if it's the best match for that, especially because my app has nothing to do with flights: [image]

I would like something more general, but I have no idea what could symbolize an ongoing event.

Comment: Are you speaking about a weather forecasters or about fortune tellers?

Comment: Weather forecasters.

Answer (score 2):

The plane symbol is indeed a bit confusing. Keep in mind that symbols/icons are often interpreted differently by users, it is therefore good practice to combine it with a label.

With regards to your questions. What about a green dot? You can even make it pulsating if that is not too distracting. Combine this with the text 'in progress' or 'active'.
[image: in progress with green dot]